# How to backup my custom defined coordinate systems in Leica Geo Office

Tags: leica-geo-office

How can I use a custom defined cs in Leica Geo Office on another PC (Leica GeoOffice instalation)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 
In case you get no help here, you'll surely get some at http://surveyorconnect.com/